# Not NaN values with jiffle based style in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sld, jiffle

I have a problem with SAVI radiometric index calc over multiband raster file.
I have Jiffle based styles for some radiometric index.
For example: NDVI:
Jiffle code:

`dest = (band8 - band4) / (band8 + band4);`

And the getfeatureinfo for a 'border pixel' (non value pixel) returns NaN value, which is good.

[image: pixel border info with NDVI]

But when I try the same with SAVI style:

`dest = (band8 - band4) / (band8 + band4 + 0.5) * 1.5;`

The value of the NaN pixels turn into 0.0 values

[image: With SAVI style]

And it image gives me an error when I request it with Leaflet

[image: Red borders in Leaflet]

I think it could be realated to data type but I don't know how to fix it

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first equation:

```
dest = (band8 - band4) / (band8 + band4);
```

if `band8` and `band4` are 0 you get `0/0` or `NaN` as you see.

While for your second equation:

```
dest = (band8 - band4) / (band8 + band4 + 0.5) * 1.5;
```

for the same 0 input you get `(0/.5) * 1.5` which is `0` so the maths is correct. You should probably add a filter to take out zero values and insert `NaN` if that is what you want.

```
dest = (band8 == 0 && band4 == 0) ? 0/0: (band8 - band4) / (band8 + band4 + 0.5) * 1.5;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @Ian. Your suggestion gives me this error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 31; columnNumber: 36; The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

Comment: You'll need to replace the `&` with `&amp;` for an XML file

Comment: Thank you Ian. Also the NaN throw the error "Expression "NaN" is not an rvalue". I replace it with 0/0 and it works as expected. Thank you for all the altruistic work. You have house in Spain when you want!

Comment: please just accept the answer to help others find it